# UWP Canvas inside Scrollviewer handle pen input like mouse input

Tags: c#, .net, canvas, uwp, scrollviewer

I have a Canvas (not InkCanvas) inside a Scrollviewer. Both are not created in XAML but in code behind. I want to draw lines on my Canvas with Pen and Mouse input, everything works just fine but now I tested the whole thing with a pen as input device and the Scrollviewer seems to recognize it as touch input because the whole thing starts scrolling.

My question is: Is it possible to tell the Scrollviewer to ignore all inputs from a device type? Because it also seems like the Scrollviewer is 'eating' the events which should be fired from the Canvas.

Here my Scrollviewer init:

```
private void SetUpScrollViewer()
    {
        scroll = new ScrollViewer();

        scroll.VerticalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Auto;
        scroll.HorizontalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Auto;
        scroll.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
        scroll.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
        scroll.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.Enabled;
        scroll.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.System;
        scroll.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        scroll.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        scroll.IsZoomInertiaEnabled = false;

        scroll.MinZoomFactor = 1;
        scroll.MaxZoomFactor = 5;
    }
```

Those are the events I use in my Canvas:

```
public void EnableDrawingOnCanvas(Canvas canvas)
    {
        //Adding the needed event handler.
        canvas.PointerPressed += Canvas_PointerPressed;
        canvas.PointerMoved += Canvas_PointerMoved;
        canvas.PointerReleased += Canvas_PointerReleased;
        canvas.PointerExited += Canvas_PointerExited;
    }
```

And those events all check if the input device is everything but touch like this

```
if (e.Pointer.PointerDeviceType != Windows.Devices.Input.PointerDeviceType.Touch){...}
```

But with those Events I can only check the input device for my Canvas and if I add a Event to the Scrollviewer it won't get passed to the Canvas afaik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind a `PointerPressed` event to your ScrollViewer and check if the `e.Pointer.PointerDeviceType` equals `PointerDeviceType.Pen`. Then you can disable the `VerticalScrollMode` the `HorizontalScrollMode` and the `ZoomMode` like in the code below.

If you want to reactivate the ScrollViewer you can bind a `PointerExited` event to your ScrollViewer and reenable everything.

```
private void Scroll_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Pointer.PointerDeviceType == PointerDeviceType.Pen)
    {
        scroll.VerticalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Disabled;
        scroll.HorizontalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Disabled;
        scroll.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.Disabled;
    }
}
```